# Keep null fields of a POJO as keys in map java

Tags: java, null, jackson, hashmap, objectmapper

I have a POJO and using object mapper to convert it into a map. I want the map to contain all fields of the POJO in it's entryset even if their value is null. So that entry might be null in the map I am creating.

```
Map<String, Object> oldDetails = objectMapper.convertValue(oldFields, Map.class);
```

I've tried using below snippet but that didn't help me.

```
objectMapper.setDefaultPropertyInclusion(JsonInclude.Value.construct(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS, JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS));
```

Any other idea that I can use here?

My POJO:

```
@JsonInclude(NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class BaseFields {

    @JsonProperty("number") protected String number;
    @JsonProperty("name") protected String name;
    @JsonProperty("dob") protected String dob;

}
```

There are other classes inheriting from BaseFields such as.

```
@JsonInclude(NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CustomerBaseFields extends BaseFields {
    @JsonProperty("email") protected String email;         
}
```

Now there is method that converts an instance of ChangedBaseFields into a map.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, true);
        objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        objectMapper.setDefaultPropertyInclusion(JsonInclude.Value.construct(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS, JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS));
        Map<String, Object> oldDetails = objectMapper.convertValue(baseFields, Map.class);
```

But say if a field like email is null in object, I'm not getting a key email in my map.

Comment: And what happened with that snippet?  Null nields are missing in the map,. NullPointertException occurred?  Please clarify.

Comment: Null fields are not in the map. Only non-null fields are part of the map.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. It works fine. Can you write a self-contained minimal executable?

Comment: Updated some code snippets, please check. @k314159

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's simple code demonstrating that your code in fact works without any additional configuration with default ObjectMapper.

```java
package java17test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.util.Map;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        
        var oldFields = new TestClass();
        oldFields.setFirstName("first name");

        Map<?, ?> oldDetails = objectMapper.convertValue(oldFields, Map.class);
        oldDetails.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + "=" + value));
    }

    static class TestClass {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
firstName=first name
lastName=null
```

Comment: I just realized that javing @JsonIgnore(NON_NULL) might be causing a problem here.

Comment: My original intention was to compare and get differences between two objects. Like I needed to know what field(s) are being updated in the new pojo.

Comment: Is there a way that I can override the @JsonIgnore property using objectmapper?

Comment: @N.Rajal You can configure your mapper with MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS, false, but it'll ignore all annotations in this case, which might be appropriate for you or not. I don't think that you can selectively disable specific annotation.

Comment: Thanks @vbezhenar I tried USE_ANNOTATION property, seems to be working fine. However there is a boolean item added called empty (as false) in all converted maps. 
Although it shouldn't be a problem but is that a default field or we can remove that as well?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an [X-Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) because you mentioned in a comment to vbezhenar's answer that your intention is to compare the fields of two objects of the same type, to find out which fields have changed.

You don't have to use Jackson to do that.

Here's a simple pure Java (no dependencies) way of comparing two objects:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Utils {
    /**
     * Compares two objects of the same type, returning the field values that are different.
     *
     * @param o1 an object
     * @param o2 another object
     * @return a map of field name to a two-element array of the two different values of o1 and o2
     */
    public static <T> Map<String, Object[]> comparePojos(T o1, T o2) throws IllegalAccessException {
        Map<String, Object[]> diffs = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        for (Field field : o1.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object[] values = {field.get(o1), field.get(o2)};
            if (!values[0].equals(values[1]))
                diffs.put(field.getName(), values);
        }
        return diffs;
    }
}

class UtilsDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException {
        SamplePojo a = new SamplePojo("alice", 42);
        SamplePojo b = new SamplePojo("bob", 42);
        Utils.comparePojos(a, b).forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ": " + Arrays.toString(v)));
    }
}

class SamplePojo {
    public SamplePojo(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ k314159, this is a good solution, but I was trying to avoid using reflection for my requirement.

Comment: @N.Rajal no worries, I see that the other answer was suitable for you, which is good, but remember that Jackson also uses reflection behind the scenes.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that.  Thanks a lot.